# How do you interpret the attacks in the Bestiary?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For example, in Bestiary 1, the Yeti has the melee attack *2 claws +9(1d6+4 plus 1d6 cold)*

Does the 2 claws part mean he gets that attack doubled?  Does the +9 go to attack bonus and damage, or just attack bonus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**As follows**

Your example reads:

> melee attack 2 claws +9(1d6+4 plus 1d6 cold)

This indicates first that the attack is a *melee* attack, made with all the rules thereof and within the yeti's reach.

The "2 claws" section is the *number* and *type* of attack it is. In this case, we have 2 natural attacks, both of which are claws - making them primary natural attacks that deal slashing damage. The PFSRD entry can tell you more.

The "+9" is the *attack bonus* of that/those attacks. If the yeti attacks with 1 claw, it's at +9; if it attacks with both claws, both attack at +9 (see the rules on full attacks and primary natural attacks).

The part in parentheses is the *damage* of those attacks. The first part is the base slashing damage of the claws plus the yeti's strength modifier. The second part is additional cold damage that is not modified when part of a critical hit (see the rules on critical hits).